# Make ExpansionTile clickable

Tags: dart, flutter

I have the flutter code below and am trying to make the text `clickable` be clickable like a button. I have used the sample code in the flutter gallery and I tried defining a field in the Entry Class a list of FlatButtons `final List<FlatButtons> bvttons` but I get an error of FlatButtons not being a type. Is there any way to make the clickable string responsive like a button?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new Demo());
}

class Demo extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new Home(title: 'Demo'),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  Home({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => new _HomeState();
}

class Entry {
  Entry(this.title, [this.children = const <Entry>[]]);
  final String title;
  final List<Entry> children;
}

final List<Entry> data = <Entry>[
  new Entry(
    'Expand', <Entry>[
      new Entry(
        'Clickable',
      ),
    ],
  )];

class EntryItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const EntryItem(this.entry);

  final Entry entry;

  Widget _buildTiles(Entry root) {
    if (root.children.isEmpty)
      return new ListTile(title: new Text(root.title));
    return new ExpansionTile(
      key: new PageStorageKey<Entry>(root),
      title: new Text(root.title),
      children: root.children.map(_buildTiles).toList(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildTiles(entry);
  }
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  Widget _buildDrawer(BuildContext context) {
    return new Drawer(
      child: new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          const DrawerHeader(
              child: const Center(child: const Text('Demo'))),
          const ListTile(
            leading: const Icon(Icons.home),
            title: const Text('Home'),
            selected: false,
          ),
          const ListTile(
            leading: const Icon(Icons.assessment),
            title: const Text('Results'),
            enabled: false,
          ),
          new ListTile(
            leading: const Icon(Icons.cached),
            title: const Text('Refresh All'),
            enabled: false,
          ),
          const Divider(),
          new ListTile(
            leading: const Icon(Icons.settings),
            title: const Text('Settings'),
            onTap: _handleShowSettings,
          ),
          new ListTile(
            leading: const Icon(Icons.feedback),
            title: const Text('Feedback'),
            enabled: false,
          ),
          new ListTile(
            leading: const Icon(Icons.help),
            title: const Text('About'),
            onTap: _handleShowAbout,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _handleShowSettings() {
    Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, '/settings');
  }

  void _handleShowAbout() {
    showAboutDialog(context: context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      drawer: _buildDrawer(context),
      body: new ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
            new EntryItem(data[index]),
        itemCount: data.length,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `ListTile`, it has constructor parameter `onTap`. You can modify `_buildTiles`:

```
Widget _buildTiles(Entry root) {
    if (root.children.isEmpty)
      return new ListTile(
        title: new Text(root.title), 
        onTap: ()=>debugPrint("I was clicked"),
        );
    return new ExpansionTile(
      key: new PageStorageKey<Entry>(root),
      title: new Text(root.title),
      children: root.children.map(_buildTiles).toList(),
    );
  }
```

Also there is short sample in [docs](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html)

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work. can I use that to navigate to a new screen, seems not to accept a context

Comment: What's problem do you have with navigation? Can you clarify?

Comment: Thought I could simply replace the onTap call with `secondPagenavi(){Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/SecondPage");}` to navigate to another page but getting an error on context: `Class 'EntryItem' has no instance getter 'context'`

Comment: You need to have reference to context. You can do it in different ways, for example your `secondPagenavi` can take parameter `context` and return new function : `secondPagenavi(context) => () =>  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/SecondPag‌​e");` and use in `onTap: secondPagenavi(context)`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, I probably am doing something wrong but unable to figure it out, thanks for your help

Comment: @driftavalii I'm having the same issue you had with the context. I'm not sure how to specify it. Did you finally solve it?